# C++ erase / remove_if - only removes from the front of the string

Tags: c++, stl

Here `str` is a `string`:

```
str.erase(std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), &islower));
```

only seems to remove lowercase characters from the front of the string. Why is that and how do I get it to remove all lowercase letters in the string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::basic_string` has two [forms of erase](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase) taking iterators; the first for erasing a single character at that position and the second for a erasing the characters from a range.

1. `iterator erase(iterator position);`
2. `iterator erase(iterator first, iterator last);`

Try the two argument form:

```
str.erase(std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), &islower), str.end());
```

It will erase the data in the range `first` to `last`, excluding `last` (thus `[first; last)`), from the position returned as the result of the `remove_if` to the end of the string.

This is **commonly known as the [erase-remove idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom)**.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing erase-remove wrong:

```
str.erase(std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), &islower), str.end());
//                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Your way uses the single-argument overload of `std::string::erase` that erases a single character, not the range overload that erases, well, a range.

*[Read the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase)!*